# .NET Core 1.0, Enumerate All classes that implement base class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I am working on migrating an ASP.NET project to RC2. I am using AutoFac to try to enumerate classes that implement AutoMapper Profile base class to set up all my mapping profiles without having to call them explicitly.  Previously in older version of ASP.NET (even in RC1) I was able to use the following code:

```
public class AutoMapperModule : Module
{

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes().AssignableTo(typeof(Profile)).As<Profile>();

        builder.Register(context =>
        {
            var profiles =
               AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
               .SelectMany(IoC.GetLoadableTypes)
               .Where(t => t != typeof(Profile) && t.Name != "NamedProfile" && typeof(Profile).IsAssignableFrom(t));

            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                foreach (var profile in profiles)
                {
                    cfg.AddProfile((Profile)Activator.CreateInstance(profile));
                }
            });
            return config;
        })
        .AsSelf()
        .As<IConfigurationProvider>()
        .SingleInstance();

        builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<MapperConfiguration>().CreateMapper(c.Resolve)).As<IMapper>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<MappingEngine>().As<IMappingEngine>();

    }
}
```

This worked fantastically, until I tried converting my project to RC2 using the new netcoreapp1.0 framework, except now I am getting a design time error on AppDomain stating the "AppDomain does not exist in the current context". I've seen some suggestions about using ILibraryManager or DependencyContext to do this but I can't figure out how to get any of that to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: does this code build okay, or do you get any errors?

Comment: in the RC1 project, targeting .net 4.5.2 it worked fine yea, been using it for a few months now. I suspect if I targeted 452 again it would work, I believe this is more of a .net core thing than an asp.net or RC1/RC2 thing. The core framework seems to have gotten rid of "AppDomain" intentionally but the replacements don't seem to be very helpful as alternatives.

Comment: This might help you: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server/blob/e2f826f95fe42df6d64d5cf4b6bf636adcfa2e19/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server/Hubs/DefaultAssemblyLocator.cs

Comment: That is indeed helpful however as I mentioned in the comment to the below answer that the assemblies are already loaded hence the "AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()" call. I don't mind loading them manually as that example is doing, however the actual goal is simply to enumerate already loaded assemblies for classes that inherit "Profile", so I can add an instance to the Automapper configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.Net Core currently (1.0 RTM) does not support `AppDomain.GetAssemblies()` or a similar API. [It's likely that it will support it in 1.1.](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/8806)

Until then, if you need this feature, you will need to stick with `net452` (i.e. .Net Framework) instead of `netcoreapp1.0`.

Comment: I unfortunately found this (using full .net 4xx framework) as the only viable solution that doesn't involve loading assemblies that are already loaded. If anybody else has any other suggestions, please do share.

Answer (score -1):

Will this work?

```
var all =
        Assembly
        .GetEntryAssembly()
        .GetReferencedAssemblies()
        .Select(Assembly.Load)
        .SelectMany(x => x.DefinedTypes)
        .Where(type => typeof(ICloudProvider).IsAssignableFrom(type.AsType()));
foreach (var ti in all)
{
    var t = ti.AsType();
    if (!t.Equals(typeof(ICloudProvider)))
    {
        // do work
    }
}
```