# What is the way of getting all implementations (classes) of some interface of current assembly in .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I want to get all implementations (classes) of some interface of current assembly and want to create instance of that classes. How I can do that?

In mvc5 framework it work like this way

```
  var type = typeof(IMyInterface);
  var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
  .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
  .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p) && !p.IsInterface);
```

but in .net core how can I do it?

Comment: I don't understand, you say you want types from current assembly, but your code gets types from all loaded assemblies. Which one is it?

Answer (score 3):

Getting all implementations:

```
var type = typeof(IMyInterface);
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
    .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p) && !p.IsInterface);
```

For creating the new object you need the `Activator`:

```
ObjectType instance = (ObjectType)Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
```

Now you only need to combine the code:

```
var type = typeof(IBase);
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
    .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p) && !p.IsInterface);

var myObjects = new List<IBase>();
foreach (var t in types)
{
    myObjects.Add((IBase)Activator.CreateInstance(t));
}
```

When it is necessary to use .Net Core 1.0 I have bad news, it is not possible to use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` or something similar. See: [.NET Core 1.0, Enumerate All classes that implement base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624454/net-core-1-0-enumerate-all-classes-that-implement-base-class)

Comment: sorry to mention it 
I want to implement it in .net core 1.0 where AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() does not work.

Comment: @AnikSaha I have updated my answer